# How to map AspNetUser table id as foreign key to another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

```
public class UserInfo
{
  public int id {get;set;} //Primary key

  public string UserId {get; set;} // Foreign key to AspNetUser - Id

  public string FirstName {get;set;}
  public string LastName {get;set;}
  ......
  ......
}
```

How can I extend the AspNetUser table in the above fashion in EF6 code first approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, the `ForeignKey` attribute this will help you:

```
public string UserId {get; set;}

[ForeignKey("UserId")]     
public AspNetUser User {get; set;}
```